# event.target returns inconsistent objects

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I built a loop to iterate and create event listeners for a given class name. The hobby project is to create a simple calculator. My logic will be using `data-...` attributes of the buttons in various functions. There are total of 24 buttons in the calculator.

My JS is at a roadblock because the `event.target` isn't returning consistent objects, so I cannot rely on when the `target` will be the correct object.

Here is en example of one html button:

```html
<button data-type="input" data-value="7" data-ignore-history="0" data-history-symbol="7" class="calcButton">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-7"></i>
</button>
```

Here is my object query:

```js
const calcButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("calcButton");
```

Here is my event listener:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < calcButtons.length; i++) {
    calcButtons[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(event.target);
        console.log(event.target.offsetParent);
        console.log(event.target.offsetParent.dataset); // need consistent access to data attributes of button
    });
}
```

Problem is that it doesn't return consistently. Sometimes the `event.target` is the button, most often it is the `<i>'fontawesome'</i>` tag. I initially expected the `<button>` tag to be the `target`, but my initial tests in the console returned the `<i>`, which is why I was using the `.offsetParent` to access the button attributes.

Further, if the issue is occurring on a certain button, it can correct after clicking on other buttons sometimes.

[image]

Comment: Use `currentTarget` instead

Comment: @Phil Can we use `this` instead of `target` or `currentTarget`?

Comment: @Shrey not with an arrow function like in OP's code

Comment: Oh! That'll represent the defined object . . .

Comment: Many thanks to all who proposed the `currentTarget` - that seems to be the linchpin @Phil @Shrey